Formulario HTML en aplicacion mongoDB no envia los datos del formulario en el request. Cual podria ser la causa?
Estoy haciendo una aplicacion usando MongoDB, y una de las funciones es para introducir un objeto en la base de datos, creado a partir de un formulario html, pero al debugar, no hay informacion dentro del body del request. Estamos usando el motor de vistas Pug.
La aplicacion se inicia en index.js
const path = require("path");
const express = require('express');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo');

const juguetes = require('./routes/juguetes');
app.use('/juguetes', juguetes);

//const contactos = require('./routes/cartas');



app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');
app.use(express.static('public'));

//app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render("cartas", { title: "Raya Directa" });
  });
/*
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('error', {texto: "ERROR 404: SITIO NO ENCONTRADO"});
});
*/

app.listen(14000);


Teninendo un enrutador para la gestion de los objetos "juguetes"
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const juguetesController = require('../controllers/juguetesController');

router.get('/', juguetesController.index);
router.get('/create',juguetesController.create);
router.post('/', juguetesController.store);
router.get('/:id/edit', juguetesController.edit);
router.put('/:id', juguetesController.update);
router.delete('/:id', juguetesController.destroy);

module.exports = router;

Con su modelo
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const juguetesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El nombre es obligatorio'],
        maxlength: [80, 'El nombre es demasiado largo']
    },
    precio: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'El precio es obligatorio'],
        min: [0, "El precio no puede ser inferior a 0"]
    },
    peso: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'El peso es oblicatorio'],
        min: [0, "El peso no puede ser inferior a 0"],
        max: [20, "El peso no puede ser superior a 20"]
    },
    stock: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'El stock es obligatorio'],
        min: [0, "El stock no puede ser inferior a 0"]
    }
    });

const Juguete = mongoose.model('juguetes', juguetesSchema);

module.exports = Juguete;

Y su controlador
const juguetes = require('../models/juguetes');

exports.index = ('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('juguetesIndex', { juguetes });
});

exports.create = ('/create', (req, res) => {
    res.render('juguetesCrear');
});

exports.store = ('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);

    let juguete = new juguetes(req.body);

    juguete.save()
    .then(() => {
        //console.log(juguete);

        res.redirect('/juguetes');
    })
    .catch(err => {

        console.log(juguete);

        let errores = [];
        let campos = Object.keys(err.errors);
        for(let campo of campos) {
            errores.push(err.errors[campo].message);
        }
        res.render('juguetesCrear', { juguete, errores });
    });
});

exports.edit = ('/:id/edit', (req, res) => {
});

exports.update = ('/:id', (req, res) => {
});

exports.destroy = ('/:id', (req, res) => {

});


La vista con el formulario en si.
extends template.pug

block content
    div.container.m-5
        div.row
            div.offset-3.col-6
                h3.text-muted.mb-5 Datos del juguetes
                form.form-horizontal(role="form", action="/juguetes/", method="post")
                    div.form-group
                        input.form-control.input-lg.panel-primary#nombre(type="text", name="nombre",  placeholder="Nombre del juguete")
                    div.form-group
                        input.form-control.input-lg.panel-primary#precio(type="number", name="precio", placeholder="Precio del juguete") 
                    div.form-group
                        input.form-control.input-lg.panel-primary#peso(type="number", name="peso", placeholder="Peso del juguete")
                    div.form-group
                        input.form-control.input-lg.panel-primary#stock(type="number", name="stock", placeholder="Stock del juguete")
                    div.form-group.text-right.mt-5
                        button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit") Crear
                if errores
                    div.alert.alert-danger
                        each error in errores 
                            p #{error}

Y el template.pug.
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        title Agenda de contactos
        link(rel="icon", type="image/png", href="/images/favicon.png")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/bootstrap.min.css")
        script(src="/js/jquery.min.js")
        script(src="/js/popper.min.js")
        script(src="/js/bootstrap.min.js")
    body.bg-success
        nav.navbar.navbar-toggleable.navbar-inverse.bg-inverse
            a.navbar-brand(href="/") Mongo Reyes
            div.collapse.navbar-collapse#navbarCollapse
                ul.navbar-nav.mr-auto
                    li.nav-item
                        a(href='/')
                            img(src='./images/reyes.png' alt='Reyes')
                    li.nav-item
                        a.nav-link(href="/juguetes") Ver juguetes
                    li.nav-item
                        a.nav-link(href="/cartas") Ver cartas
        block content

En el primer Log, donde compruebo el body del request, me sale que esta undefined, y en el segundo, que se ejecuta cuando hay un error al intentar guardar el objeto en la base de datos, me sale que el objeto unicamente tiene como campo la ID

Que esta causando que no se pasen los datos en el formulario?

Mueve la linea de app.use(express.urlencoded... de posición, de tal manera que se ejecute antes de la declaración de tu ruta juguetes. Sucede que cuando se carga la app, el middleware que procesa el cuerpo de la solicitud está siendo cargado después de la declaración de ruta, por lo cual nunca va a procesar el cuerpo que envíes a esa ruta. Comenta el resultado, para saber si esto soluciona el problema.

Como sugerencia, que encontrarás incluso en la documentación de Express, los middleware de aplicación debes siempre declararlos primero que las rutas, por razones obvias. Las rutas deberían ser siempre lo último en usar en tu aplicación, salvo algunos casos específicos como el capturador de errores o el capturador de todas las demás rutas no declaradas en tu Router.

Eso lo ha solucionado, gracias.
